# How to prove $(p \lor q); (p\rightarrow r); (q\rightarrow s);$ therefore $(r \lor s),$ without modes tollens or derived rules for natural deduction

Tags: propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

> How to prove

$(p \lor q);$

$(p\rightarrow r);$

$(q\rightarrow s);$

therefore $(r \lor s).$

without modes tollens or derived rules for natural deduction

I can prove the above set with derived rules, (negation rules, modus tollens, etc), but is there a way to prove it using only the basic natural deduction rules. Thank you

Comment: If $p \vee q$ is true, then at least one of $p$ or $q$ is true. You can consider the individual cases and calculate $r \vee s$ in each case, showing that it is always true.

Comment: Edited post, but wasn’t sure what to make the the letters ‘A’ after 1., 2., and 3.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm guessing "Assumption", though they are given as premises in the title.

Comment: @amWhy Well premises *are* undischarged assumptions.

Comment: @GrahamKemp  Sure.  Thanks for confirming my response to Thomas Andrews.

Answer (score 4):

From the first premise, we have $p\lor q$.

$\qquad$ Assume p.  Then r. (Modus ponens, first premise plus premise 2).  Then $r\lor s$.

$\qquad$ Assume q.  Then s. (Modus ponens,  first premise, plus premise 3). Then $r\lor s$.

Therefore $r\lor s$.

I'll let you complete the justifications.

Comment: Justice is the lost word nowadays...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, one of the premises is a disjunction, so a *disjunction elimination* would seem promising.

At the other end, the target is a disjunction, so *disjunction introduction* is also indicated.

Now, for the in-between, the other two premises are conditional statements, whose antecedents and consequents look most useful, so...